# Creating a table linked to a csv file

Tags: javascript, d3.js, html-table

I am trying to create a table linked to a `*.csv` file using d3, but all I get is a blank webpage.
Even with the example Crimea I get a blank page.
I would be grateful to be directed or shown a working example or a suggestion of what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Please show us some code that replicates the problem.

Comment: See also the example given in the D3 docs for selection.data(): https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#data

Answer (score 83, accepted):

If you're asking about creating an HTML table from CSV data, this is what you want:

```
d3.csv("data.csv", function(data) {
    // the columns you'd like to display
    var columns = ["name", "age"];

    var table = d3.select("#container").append("table"),
        thead = table.append("thead"),
        tbody = table.append("tbody");

    // append the header row
    thead.append("tr")
        .selectAll("th")
        .data(columns)
        .enter()
        .append("th")
            .text(function(column) { return column; });

    // create a row for each object in the data
    var rows = tbody.selectAll("tr")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("tr");

    // create a cell in each row for each column
    var cells = rows.selectAll("td")
        .data(function(row) {
            return columns.map(function(column) {
                return {column: column, value: row[column]};
            });
        })
        .enter()
        .append("td")
            .text(function(d) { return d.value; });
});
```

Check out the [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/7WQjr/). If you're copying that code, you'll need to update the `tabulate()` function so that it either selects an existing table or a different container (rather than `"#container"`), then you can use it with CSV data like so:

```
d3.csv("path/to/data.csv", function(data) {
  tabulate(data, ["name", "age"]);
});
```

Comment: This example does not work fir me currently,  the td elements are empty.  Can you please see this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23399462/d3-table-example-yields-empty-td-tags

Comment: Thanks Shawn, you shaved off a task on my list with this answer.

Comment: @shawn-allen can this be used to generate table to calculate daily min/max and average for a CSV containing 1 month ofg data

Answer (score 5):

There is a bug in the answer proposed by @Shawn_allen.

To solve it just change the following line of code

```
return {column: column, value: row[column]};
```

by this one

```
return {column: column, value: row[columns.indexOf(column)]};
```

Enjoy !

Answer (score 1):

Often, I need to refresh a table of data periodically.  Here's how I populate a table with data:

HTML:

```
<table id="t1">
    <thead>
        <tr><th>Name<th>Age
    </thead>
</table>
```

JavaScript:

```
function tabulate(data, columns) {
  var table = d3.select("#t1");
  table.select('tbody').remove();  // remove any existing data
  var tbody = table.append('tbody');
  data.forEach(function(row) {
    var tr = tbody.append('tr');
    columns.forEach(function(column) {
      tr.append('td').text(row[column]);
    });
  });
  return table;
}
```

Notes:

- I like to put table headers in the HTML, rather than generate them from JavaScript.
- I didn't attach the data to the table rows and cells (like @Shawn shows in his answer), because I don't have a need for that.  So the code is simpler.

<kbd>[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/xywo7h90/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to add this in as a new answer but I don't have enough points to add it in as a comment. Just a slight tweak to the end of the code of @Shawn_Allen. I believe that this works too.

```
//create a cell in each row for each column
var cells = rows.selectAll("td")
    .data(function(row) {
        return columns.map(function(column) {
            return row[column];
        });
    })
    .enter()
    .append("td")
        .text(function(d) { return d; });
```

});

There was no need to create that JSON with column, value.