# D3 creating a table

Tags: javascript, d3.js

According to the solution given here : [Creating a table linked to a csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9268645/d3-creating-a-table-linked-to-a-csv-file)

I don't understand what happens at this part of the code :

```
var cells = rows.selectAll("td")
        .data(function(row) {
            return columns.map(function(column) {
                return row[column];
            });
        })
```

I know that data() will loop on each elements in my array 'row' and that Array.prototype.map() will "create a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array".

At `return columns.map(function(column)`, what 'column' exactly is ?

I would be grateful if someone can explain me, step by step, the loop formed by the two anonymous functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an example of a [nested selection](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/). To understand it, you also need to consider the bit of code before it that binds data to the rows.

What happens in this bit of code is that you're telling the `data()` function to consider each of the individual elements of the array passed in in the previous `data()` call

```
var rows = tbody.selectAll("tr")
    .data(data)
    ...
```

Each of these elements will now be handled in turn and be called `row`. The inner anonymous function takes this row and for each element of `columns`, gets the element from `row` that is designated by the particular `column`.

That is, `row` is an associative array (or an object) with keys of the same names as the elements in the `columns` array. All the `map` does it extract those elements into an array, which is then used as the data for the particular `td` cell.

After all the internal processing, an array is passed to `data()` -- although a single array element was passed in, an array is returned. This way a table can be created with rows and columns (and this is the point of having a nested selection). The thing that will be bound to each `td` cell is whatever the innermost `return` returns.

And to answer your specific question, the `column` variable will be bound to each element of the `columns` array in turn. That is, during the first iteration of `map()`, it will be `columns[0]`, during the second one `columns[1]` etc.