# D3 Table Example with Array of Arrays Yields Empty TD Tags

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to create a table with d3.js following [this example](http://www.d3noob.org/2013/02/add-html-table-to-your-d3js-graph.html).  Namely this is the code I am using

```
var table = d3.select("#myTableDiv").append("table")
                .attr("style", "margin-left: 0px"),
            thead = table.append("thead"),
            tbody = table.append("tbody");

        // append the header row
        thead.append("tr")
            .selectAll("th")
            .data(columns)
            .enter()
            .append("th")
            .text(function(column) { return column; });

        // create a row for each object in the data
        var rows = tbody.selectAll("tr")
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append("tr");

        // create a cell in each row for each column
        var cells = rows.selectAll("td")
            .data(function(row) {
                return columns.map(function(column) {
                    return {column: column, value: row[column]};
                });
            })
            .enter()
            .append("td")
            .attr("style", "font-family: Courier")
            .html(function(d) { return d.value; });
```

I am passing in data that looks like a standard AoA, something like this:

```
[
    [
       '2013-10',
        18000,
        43,
    ],
    [
       '2013-10',        
       224500,
       22,
    ],
}
```

But when the javascript above executes, the table contains the correct number of rows and columns, but the data itself is empty

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td style="font-family: Courier"></td>
        <td style="font-family: Courier"></td>
        <td style="font-family: Courier"></td>  
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="font-family: Courier"></td>
        <td style="font-family: Courier"></td>
        <td style="font-family: Courier"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

In fact when I alert the contents of the d variable, I see this

```
{
    'column' => 'month',
    'value' => [undefined]
}
```

Clearly there is something wrong here:

```
return {column: column, value: row[column]};
```

Comment: Can you give us a clearer picture of the data you're passing in? 

`var data` and `var columns`

Comment: In particular, it looks like you're passing in hierarchical JSON, but the example uses flat CSV.

Comment: as i staed in the post, the data is an array of arrays `[
    [
       '2013-10',
        18000,
        43,
    ],
    [
       '2013-10',        
       224500,
       22,
    ],
}`

Comment: why do you think i am passing json?

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the problem of the value of columns, you have to change the following line of code

```
return {column: column, value: row[column]};
```

by this one

```
return {column: column, value: row[columns.indexOf(column)]};
```

Enjoy !