# How to add header row to d3.csv generated table

Tags: d3.js

How do I place the first row of entries in a csv file into a table heading using d3.csv?

Here's my csv data file:

```
Surname,Name,Phone,eMail
Stupich,Andrew,719-817-2323,Andy@foo.org
Miles,Wally,719-415-7177,Wally@foo.org
McLaren,Brenda,719-817-1096,Brenda@foo.org
```

Here's my html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"> 
<head> 
    <meta charset="utf-8"> 
    <title>D3.csv Demo</title>
    <style type="text/css"> 
        body {
            margin-left: 4%;
            margin-right: 4%;
        }
        table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            border: 2px #000 solid;
        }
        th {
            border: 1px #F00 solid;
            text-align: center;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        td {
            border: 1px #00F solid;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 5px;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"> 
        d3.text("DemoData.csv", function(datasetText) {
        var parsedCSV = d3.csv.parseRows(datasetText);
        var sampleHTML = d3.select("#viz6")
            .append("table")

            .selectAll("tr")
            .data(parsedCSV)
            .enter().append("tr")

            .selectAll("td")       
            .data(function(d){return d;})       
            .enter().append("td")
            .text(function(d){return d;})
        });
    </script>   
</head>
<body>
    <h1>D3.csv Demo</h1>
  <div id="viz6"></div>
</body> 
</html>
```

How and where do I place `th` row?  Does it have something to do with d3.text vs d3.csv?

Thanks for your help; please be patient, I'm completely new to d3.csv with js - not quite certain how any of it works - what documentation I can find is completely incomprehensible to a beginner.
(I'm comfortable with HTML/CSS/PHP)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a table linked to a csv file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9268645/creating-a-table-linked-to-a-csv-file)

Comment: Side note: your meta charset tag is missing a quote (`"`). If you look in your Developer tools / Console (Ctrl + Shift + K in Firefox, F12 in Chromium) you should have caught that.

Comment: Hmmm.  The suggested resource "Creating a table linked to a CSV file" is no help.  It requires you know the content of the first row of the .csv file before you read the file!  I want to read in the first row from the .csv file and use the entries in that row as the heading for the rest of the file contents.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [parseRows](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV#parseRows) function takes a string and returns a array of arrays. You must split this array yourself into the header fields (`rows[0]`) and body elements (elements starting at index 1, `rows.slice(1)`):

```
d3.text("DemoData.csv", function (datasetText) {
    var rows = d3.csv.parseRows(datasetText);
    var tbl = d3.select("#viz6")
        .append("table");

    // headers
    tbl.append("thead").append("tr")
        .selectAll("th")
        .data(rows[0])
        .enter().append("th")
        .text(function(d) {
            return d;
        });

    // data
    tbl.append("tbody")
        .selectAll("tr").data(rows.slice(1))
        .enter().append("tr")

        .selectAll("td")
        .data(function(d){return d;})
        .enter().append("td")
        .text(function(d){return d;})
});
```

If you are going to use the [`d3.csv()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV#csv) function, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/9507713/427545. When the keys are not known beforehand, then you can use the [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) function on the data element to retrieve an array of keys. Note: the order of those keys are [not guaranteed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5525795/427545)!

Comment: @Andy Your welcome. If your question is answered, please mark this answer as accepted by clicking the tick on the left of this post.