# Creating a table with d3.js from the properties in a geojson object

Tags: javascript, d3.js, html-table, geojson

I am trying to create a table containing the the properties for each of the features listed in an inline geojson object.

The following nearly gets what I want but it only shows the properties for the first entry. How should I alter it so that shows the properties for all entries?

```
var thedatatable = d3.select("#propertiestable")
    .append("table")
    .attr("class", "datatable");

var header = thedatatable.selectAll("th")
    .data(d3.keys(datapointsjson.features[0].properties))
    .enter()
    .append("th")
    .text(function (d) {
        return d
    });

var tr = thedatatable.selectAll("tr")
    .data(d3.values(datapointsjson.features[0].properties))
    .enter()
    .append("tr");

var td = thedatatable.selectAll("td")
    .data(d3.values(datapointsjson.features[0].properties))
    .enter()
    .append("td")
    .text(function (d) {
        return d
    });
```

I'm reasonably sure that it's the "td" bit that I'm getting wrong but nothing I try shows more than just the first entry.

This is the geojson I'm working from, it needs to be inline in the same file.

```
var datapointsjson = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                136.33, -31.5
            ]
        },
        "properties": {
            "regno": "R123456",
            "taxon": "genus1 species1",
            "sitecode": "",
            "nearestnamedplace": "FREELING ISLAND",
            "preciselocation": "south coast",
            "collection": "Herpetology"
        }
    }, {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                137.07, -36.23
            ]
        },
        "properties": {
            "regno": "R654185",
            "taxon": "genus2 species2",
            "sitecode": "",
            "nearestnamedplace": "Neptune Island",
            "preciselocation": "Middle of island",
            "collection": "Herpetology"
        }
    }, {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                142.0358, -38.7719
            ]
        },
        "properties": {
            "regno": "R6528445",
            "taxon": "genus3 species3",
            "sitecode": "TT02",
            "nearestnamedplace": "Woolongong",
            "preciselocation": "5 km N",
            "collection": "Herpetology"
        }
    }, {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                137.6914, -32.2789
            ]
        },
        "properties": {
            "regno": "R654987",
            "taxon": "genus4 species4",
            "sitecode": "IL0601",
            "nearestnamedplace": "Ballarat",
            "preciselocation": "5.3 KM E",
            "collection": "Herpetology"
        }
    }]
};
```

I've made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kmaguire/nZm48/) showing the result

Any advice would be gratefully received. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've bumped your fiddle to [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4SSg3/) a lot of which is based on Shawn Allen fantastic answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9268645/creating-a-table-linked-to-a-csv-file).

For now, you needed to provide an array so d3 could iterate over them (in this case 4 times)

```
var tr = thedatatable.selectAll("tr")
    .data(d3.values(datapointsjson.features))
    .enter()
    .append("tr");
```

Then you needed to extract the info you needed from the json using:

```
var td = tr.selectAll("td")
    .data(function(row) {
        return headers.map(function(d) { console.log(row.properties)
            return {column: d, value: row.properties[d]};
        });
    })
    .enter()
    .append("td")
    .text(function (d) {
        return d.value;
    });
```

Comment: Thanks so much - that works perfectly, and the links helped with understanding what you were doing